# Reproduce custom channel groupings using Multi-Channel API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the Multi-Channel API from Google analytics to access a custom assisted conversion report which uses the channel groupings I defined.

Since the custom channel groupings aren't accessible themselves through the API, I sought to reproduce them using filter. For example, this group

Bank referral := source contains "bank"

translates to

filter=mcf:source=@bank

however the API keeps returning me assisted conversions bigger than what is displayed in Google Analytics. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

user2067450 - if you apply filters through MCF API, it will work as a filter for standard channel groupings. As you correctly pointed out, custom groupings are not YET available via API. This issue has been raised numerous times with Google (through GACP program), so hopefully this will be "fixed" soon!