# Access Google MCF Reporting API via custom model & grouping

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I have a PHP script to access the [Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API (mcf-api)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/) as a system service.

Now I am trying to access the mcf-api via a custom model and custom channel grouping data.

UPDATE:
I only can access the default channel grouping and/or default models of the multi channel funnel but some of my coworkers implemented a couple of custom channel grouping and attributions and i want to get these report via api. but there is no information how to do it.

i found some other guy with a similar question:
[Reproduce custom channel groupings using Multi-Channel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195364/reproduce-custom-channel-groupings-using-multi-channel-api)

My initial idea was to just to specify the dimension as 'myCustomGroupingName' but that did not work at all ;) so i leave it at 'mcf:basicChannelGrouping'

```
        $mcf = $service->data_mcf->get(
            'ga:'.$this->analyticsProfilId,
            '2015-02-22',
            '2015-02-23',
            'mcf:assistedConversions,mcf:assistedValue,mcf:firstInteractionConversions,mcf:firstInteractionValue,mcf:lastInteractionConversions,mcf:lastInteractionValue',
            array(
                'dimensions' => 'mcf:basicChannelGrouping'
            )
        );
```

It seems that Google hasn't implemented the api query to get custom attribution data?

UPDATE:
i got some feedback from a analytics premium support; there is atm no chance to get the data - i will be a feature in the future....

Comment: added link, clarified the question